# What's the Haskell way of using the same name for two different value constructors?

Tags: haskell, types, constructor

Let's say I want to model to-dos agreed upon between a manager and an employee in a one-on-one. A to-do might have to be realized by either the manager or the employee. Let's say I want to process some data about an employee, so I model the employee like this:

```hs
data Employee = Employee
  { id :: Int
  , name :: String
  }
```

Let's further say I'd model my to-dos like this:

```hs
data Todo = Todo
  { id :: Int
  , text :: String
  , realizedBy :: RealizedBy
  }
```

I'd find it most elegant to model the `RealizedBy`-type like this:

```hs
data RealizedBy = Manager | Employee
```

Of course, this is will not compile, as there are `` Multiple declarations of `Employee' ``.

A solution I came up with would be to not define a `RealizedBy`-type, but to model it like this:

```hs
data TodoContent = TodoContent
  { id :: Int
  , text :: String
  }

data Todo = ManagerTodo TodoContent | EmployeeTodo TodoContent
```

To me, this seems a bit over-engineered. To me, having to repeat `TodoContent` is not that elegant. Also, I can't think of better names than `Employee` for either the type or the parameterless constructor (or whatever that's called) that would model the data as well. I can't shake the feeling that I might be missing something obvious that would solve this more elegantly. Am I, or is this really the way it's meant to be modeled in Haskell?

Comment: Why not `data RealizedBy = RealizedByManager | RealizedByEmployee`

Comment: The problem is not "using the same name for a data type and a parameterless value constructor"; you are simply trying to use the same name for two different value constructors. (Note you are already successfully using `Employee` as both a type constructor and a data constructor.)

Comment: @chepner: That's right, I adjusted the title. I'm still fairly new to Haskell and am obviously missing some understanding about it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Of course, using different names would solve the problem, but I'd like to stay as close to the domain wording / model as possible. I'd rather use my solution than yours, because to me, it would model the data a bit better.

Comment: @causaprima: but you do not need to mention the attributes, so an object could look like `Todo 14 "foobar" RealizedByManager`, this looks readable to what the `RealizedByManager` is about, whereas `Todo 14 "foobar" Manager` would not provide such hint.

Comment: You don't need to specify this like is done with an enum in a lot of languages (like Java) for example as `RealizedBy.Manager`, it is simply `Manager` in that case, which does not really hint what the `Manager` is doing there.

Comment: Seems like `RealizedBy` should really be something like `data EmployeeType = Manager | Regular`. Such a type could be used both by `Todo` and `Employee` itself.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Fair point, I didn't think about what it would look like when calling the constructor. But then again, ```Todo 14 "foobar" RealizedByManager``` is not that much different from ```ManagerTodo 14 "foobar"```. Does any of those have a strong pro / con? I can't think of any, but my experience with Haskell is very limited.

Comment: @chepner: But then my ```Todo``` would have a field of type ```EmployeeType``` - that doesn't seem right. Also, one-on-ones are held by managers with their subordinates, and the software is thought to model the data from the view of a manager recording one-on-ones with her or his subordinates. Thus, I do not want to process the data of the manager, and hence I don't need to distinguish the employee type for an employee.

Comment: The type name does not have to describe the field; that's what the *field* name is for. Is `realizedBy` supposed to indicate either a specific manager or specific employee associated with the `ToDo` item?

Comment: @chepner: That correct, but a field ```realizedBy``` with the value ```Regular``` doesn't seem to describe its meaning well. A ```ToDo``` is associated with a specific employee the manager is having one-on-ones with. Either that employee has to realize the to-do, or the manager her-/himself. As only the manager is using the software to record the one-on-ones with her/his employees, from that point of view there are no other managers and thus no need to have a specific manager, only a specific employee. I hope that's not too confusing :)

Comment: OK, I'd recommend something like `data RealizedBy = Reviewer | Reviewee` then.

Comment: You simply cannot define the same constructor name multiple times in the same module. Even if you managed to do so, how would you expect the compiler (or a reader) to know when you use the source code text `Employee` which one is meant? This is not different in kind than the difficulties you would have, say, in Java working with multiple classes of the same name. Names identify things to the language; using the same name for different things simply isn't always possible. If not you give them different names, or you put them in different modules and use qualified imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell has just one mechanism for namespacing of data declarations, its module system. You can use it here.

```
module Classifications where

data RealizedBy = Manager | Employee

module Entities where

import qualified Classifications as C

data Employee = Employee Int String
data Todo = Todo Int String C.RealizedBy
```

Comment: Of course, I should have thought of that, as this is how you do it in other languages as well. However, as I'll probably use the module for other "central" types / enums as well, I named it ```enums```, but that's a minor implementation detail.